# do a animation with 3 actions in swift

Tags: swift, animation, jquery-animate, cgrect, completion

I want my swift code to do a animation with the separate and different actions. That are in sequential order. The first 2 animations work however when I add the 3rd animation it does not work anymore and causes a compile error. You can see the 3rd animation where the comment is.  I just want to get all 3 animations to work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    var block1 = UIView()

    var btn = UIButton()
  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [block1,btn].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
   
        block1.backgroundColor = .yellow
 
        btn.backgroundColor = .red
        
        block1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height * 0.1)
 
        
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100)
        btn.backgroundColor = .red
        
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(diverse), for: .touchDown)
    }
    
    @objc func diverse(){
        
        //1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            
            self.block1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 200)
            self.block1.center = self.view.center
            
        })
        //2
        { done in
            if done {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 11, animations: {
                    
                    self.block1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 22, height: 100)
                    self.block1.center = self.view.center
                    
                })
                
                
                
                
                
            }
        }
        //3 does not work
        { done in
            if done {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 11, animations: {
                    
                    self.block1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 2, height: 100)
                    self.block1.center = self.view.center
                    
                })
                
                
                
                
                
            }
        }
        
        
      
        

        
        
    }
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate) for `animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)` shows its declaration, which is this:

```
class func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, 
        animations: @escaping () -> Void, 
        completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

The `completion` argument label takes in a closure, which gets called when the animation finishes.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    self.block1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 200)
    self.block1.center = self.view.center
}) { done in /// closure here

}
```

However, there is no argument label for a second completion closure. That is why

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    self.block1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 200)
    self.block1.center = self.view.center
}) { done in /// closure here

} { done in /// second closure? Nope.

}
```

... does not compile.

Instead, what you want to do is

- put the second animation in the completion handler of the first
- put the third animation in the completion handler of the second

```
/// start first animation
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    self.block1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 200)
    self.block1.center = self.view.center
}) { done in

    /// first animation finished, start second
    if done {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 11, animations: {
            
            self.block1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 22, height: 100)
            self.block1.center = self.view.center
            
        }) { done in

            /// second animation finished, start third
            if done {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 11, animations: {
                    
                    self.block1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 2, height: 100)
                    self.block1.center = self.view.center
                    
                })
            }

        }
    }
}
```